# T-SQL Running Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Consider a table of the following shape `(wallet, client, date)`, where `wallet` and `client` are `strings`, and `date` is any date until today.
Say one wants to get the running sum of both the unique clients, and clients, for each month of the present year, grouped by wallet and month.
I have tried several things, including partitioning, but I just can't get it to work properly.

The outcome would be something like:

```
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
|    Wallet  |  Unique |  Count     | Month   |
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| Wallet1    | 2       |   5        |   1     | - For < 01022019
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| Wallet1    | 3       |   7        |   2     | - For < 01032019
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
```

And so on. I have tried many things, even partitioning, but I'm failing. I only managed to make this into several small queries all using WHERE below the date, which is absolutely awful, .e.g

```
INSERT INTO 
    tmp_tbl_filtered
SELECT
    [Wallet],
    COUNT(DISTINCT [Client]) AS [unique],
    COUNT([Client]) AS [count],
    1 AS [month]
FROM
    tmp_tbl
WHERE [Date] < '20190201'
GROUP BY  [Wallet]
ORDER BY [Wallet]

INSERT INTO 
    tmp_tbl_filtered
SELECT
    [Wallet],
    COUNT(DISTINCT [Client]) AS [unique],
    COUNT([Client]) AS [count],
    2 AS [month]
FROM
    tmp_tbl
WHERE [Date] < '20190301'
GROUP BY  [Wallet]
ORDER BY [Wallet]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right

```
SELECT [Wallet], [month]
   , SUM([unique]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Wallet] ORDER BY [month]) [unique_rt]
   , SUM([count]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Wallet] ORDER BY [month]) [count_rt]
FROM (
    --  group data of the current year 2019 by wallet and month
    SELECT 
        [Wallet],
        DATEPART(month,[Date]) AS [month],
        COUNT(DISTINCT [Client]) AS [unique],
        COUNT([Client]) AS [count]
    FROM
        tmp_tbl
    WHERE [Date] >= '20190101'
    GROUP BY [Wallet], DATEPART(month,[Date])
) t
ORDER BY [Wallet], [month]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the cumulative part comes into play.

```
SELECT YEAR(date), MONTH(date), Wallet,
       COUNT(DISTINCT [Client]) AS [unique],
       COUNT([Client]) AS [count],
FROM tmp_tbl
WHERE [Date] < '20190301'
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), [Wallet]
ORDER BY Wallet, YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Comment: Its cumulative for two reasons:
- The value for January, is the value for January 2019, and all the other years (Jan, Feb, Mar (...) 2018, 2017, (...))
- The value for Feb, is Feb's + Jan's (including the accumulated)

Comment: @GAMT312 . . . (1) Without sample data, the logic really isn't clear.  (2) It is unclear what "cumulative unique clients" are supposed to be.